# Generate table from an Entity with auto increment primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

In our application, we generate our database tables from our JPA entities. I need to create an entity will generate a table with auto-incrementing primary keys. Subsequently, I need to be able to execute plain SQL inserts without the PK present (outside of Hibernate).

E.g. `INSERT INTO ApplicationLog VALUES ('logtime', 'logpackage' ,'logclass','method', 'message')`

I've tried a few of the strategies like GenerationType.IDENTITY, AUTO, TABLE but none works when I call the above insert statement.

```
@Entity
public class ApplicationLog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="logtime")
    private String datetime;
    @Column(name="logpackage")
    private String _package;
    @Column(name="logclass")
    private String _class;
    private String method;
    private String message;
    ...
}
```

I would get the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "asdf"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO ApplicationLog VALUES ('asdf', 'ee' ,'cc','33', ...
```

My application has to support SqlServer (2012+), Postgres (9+) and Oracle (11g+) so the application needs to remain as database agnostic as possible.

As a bit of background info, my set up is simply to allow for the use of Log4j's JDBCAppender, so I can log to the db and read the records in the app using Hibernate (for display).

Comment: Beware that Oracle doesn't support auto increment fields. You'll have to use sequences and triggers instead to emmulate such feature. Consequently it brokes with `GenerationType.IDENTITY`.

Comment: I guess I could do some special processing for Oracle, but it seems GenerationType.IDENTITY should work with Postgres and SqlServer, but it's not.

Comment: databases have their own structure for generating PKs. as dic19 mentioned, for Oracle you need to use Sequence, therefore in your entity you must specify `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`.
Why don't you use `CreateNativeQuery` instead?